# how to prevent autoclose tooltip in apache echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

how to prevent close tooltip when mouse outside chart?

I have a chart with tooltip settings:

```
 {
          trigger: 'item',
          triggerOn: 'click',
          formatter: () => 'some html markup',
          enterable: true,
          padding: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(32,31,34,0.9)',
          confine: true
}
```

But he is close when mouse leave chart, anybody know how to prevent it?

I tried execute event.preventDefault on 'globalout' event chart event. But it doesn't work

I don't wont write own inmplementation of it :(

Comment: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip - Search for `tooltip.alwaysShowContent` for the explanation.